# I need when choosing a name to automatically select email address of this person in DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

In my application in first page I input person's data(name, email, etc...), and in second page I choose person to to give him a book. And I need automatic selection email in second page when I choosing a name in DropDownListFor. Models are different!!!!! Thanks!

Here is controller of first page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcLib.Models;
using MvcLibraly.Models;

namespace MvcLibraly.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        private BookDBContext db = new BookDBContext();

        //
        // GET: /Users/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Users/Details/5


        public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
        {
            var users = from m in db.Users
                         select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = users.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(users);
        }


        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Users/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Users/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Users/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Users/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Users/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Users/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is view of first page:

```
@model MvcLib.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Добавление читателя";
}

<h2>Добавление читателя</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

       @* <div class="editor-label">
            Фамилия
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)*@
        @*</div>*@

        <div class="editor-label">
            Ф.И.О.
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

       @* <div class="editor-label">
            Отчество
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>*@

        <div class="editor-label">
            Год рождения
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Телефон
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            E-mail
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adress, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Группа
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Group)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Group, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Вернуться к списку читателей", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here is controller of second page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcLibraly.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO; 


namespace MvcLibraly.Controllers
{
    public class UchetController : Controller
    {
        private BookDBContext db = new BookDBContext();

        //
        // GET: /Uchet/ !!!!!!!!!!!!

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Uchets.ToList());
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Uchet uchet)
        {
            return View(uchet);
        }


        //
        // GET: /Uchet/Details/5


        //public ActionResult SearchIndex(string bookName, string searchString)
        //{


        //}







        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {



            Uchet uchet = db.Uchets.Find(id);
            if (uchet == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(uchet);
        }

        public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
        {
            var users = from m in db.Uchets
                        select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = users.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(users);
        }


        //
        // GET: /Uchet/Create

        public ActionResult Create(string userName, string nameTitle, string nameAdress)
        {
            var NameLst = new List<string>();

            var NameQry = from b in db.Users
                          orderby b.Name
                          select b.Name;
            NameLst.AddRange(NameQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.userName = new SelectList(NameLst);

            var TitleLst = new List<string>();

            var TitleQry = from r in db.Lib
                           orderby r.Title
                           select r.Title;
            TitleLst.AddRange(TitleQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.nameTitle = new SelectList(TitleLst);


            var AdressLst = new List<string>();

            var AdressQry = from j in db.Users
                            orderby j.Name
                            select j.Adress;
            AdressLst.AddRange(AdressQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.nameAdress = new SelectList(AdressLst);





            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Uchet/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Uchet uchet)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Uchets.Add(uchet);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(uchet);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Uchet/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(string userName, string nameTitle, string nameAdress, int id = 0)
        {
            var NameLst = new List<string>();

            var NameQry = from b in db.Users
                          orderby b.Name
                          select b.Name;
            NameLst.AddRange(NameQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.userName = new SelectList(NameLst);

            var TitleLst = new List<string>();

            var TitleQry = from r in db.Lib
                           orderby r.Title
                           select r.Title;
            TitleLst.AddRange(TitleQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.nameTitle = new SelectList(TitleLst);


            var AdressLst = new List<string>();

            var AdressQry = from j in db.Users
                            orderby j.Name
                            select j.Adress;
            AdressLst.AddRange(AdressQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.nameAdress = new SelectList(AdressLst);





            Uchet uchet = db.Uchets.Find(id);
            if (uchet == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(uchet);



        }

        //
        // POST: /Uchet/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Uchet uchet)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(uchet).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(uchet);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Uchet/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Uchet uchet = db.Uchets.Find(id);
            if (uchet == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(uchet);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Uchet/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Uchet uchet = db.Uchets.Find(id);
            db.Uchets.Remove(uchet);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is view of second page:  UPDATED!!!

```
@model MvcLibraly.Models.Uchet

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Выдача книги";
}

<h2>Выдача книги</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Uchet</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Выберите читателя:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @*@Html.DropDownList("userName", "Выберите читателя...", model.Name)*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, (SelectList)ViewBag.userName, new { style = "width: 310px" }) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Выберите адрес:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Adress, (SelectList)ViewBag.nameAdress, new { style = "width: 310px" }) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adress, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            Выберите название книги:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.nameTitle, new { style = "width: 310px" }) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Выберите дату выдачи книги:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePol) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatePol, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Выберите дату возврата книги:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateVoz)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateVoz, "Введены некорректные данные!")
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Создать" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: What have tried ? Have you an error?

Comment: @lnanikian Email in second page not select automatic...

Comment: Why do you use 2 controllers for the same model? If you want your second Email be automatic you need to pass the selected value. When you choose from the first page you have a value, then you pass this value to the action which creates the dropDown selectList and then use it for the selected value by default. Check the overload of SelectList():

Comment: @lnanikian Ohhh, sorry I forgot to say that they are different models ...

Comment: I only see editor for on your second view.  I don't see an email drop down.

Comment: @MattBodily Ouch! I was wrong, attached the same views twice, now corrected second view!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a drop down in your second page but here is how to default the value.  In a DropDownListFor the selected value is set by the value in the lambda expression.  So in your model you need to add a selected field

```
public string SelectedEmail { get; set; }
```

on your controller you set the selected value by setting that field

```
model.SelectedEmail = //value based on view 1 selection
```

then in your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedEmail, Model.EmailList)
```

This will set the selected value in your drop down and if they change that value on the drop down it will come back to the controller in that SelectedEmail field.

Comment: Shit, I again sent wrong view :D Now updated again!)